In VxWorks, how can I list the names of all threads, then kill one of them?
From memory, in Linux, I can ps -a or similar, then kill -9 <pid>, although that might be for processes.
I have a single VxWorks process (RTP) which has multiple threads. For testing, I want to list the names of the threads, then kill one which I recognize. How can I do that?
